# Control access to a sub-site

Tags: permissions, sub-site, access, inheritance

I have created a sub-site in SharePoint that is meant to be only for Management. I created the site and stopped inheriting permissions from the parent. Then I added only the managers and myself to the Visitors and Members user groups (and I trusted a few of them to be in the Owners group with full control). So the managers are the only people that I have given permissions to the site, but for some reason all other users can still access and view the sub-site. They can't make changes or anything, but I need to prevent access to that sub-site to anyone who has not been given permissions.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening? Would this be a problem with permissions at the parent site?

For reference, when I check the permissions of someone I did not give access to the sub-site I am told that they have no permissions but that the following factors also affect their level of access:

- Allow: View Web Analytics Data
- Allow: Browse Directories
- Allow: View Items
- Allow: View Pages
- Allow: Enumerate Permissions
- Allow: Open Items
- Allow: View Versions
- Allow: Browse User Information
- Allow: View Application Pages
- Allow: Use Remote Interfaces
- Allow: Use Client Integration Features
- Allow: Open

**EDIT**

I have managed to resolve the issue. The problem was that the person who originally created the site and set everything up gave all users full read access everywhere in Central Administration. This was overriding the broken inheritance of my sub site from the main site, and is why the permissions weren't related to a group and why I couldn't find the source of the granted permissions within the main site.

**EDIT**

My above edit turned out to not be the solution. Removing Full Read access from the Central Admin area only made all of my sites inaccessible, even to Admins. I am guessing that something else is wrong with the permissions somewhere else.

Comment: Did you removed all users from that subsite?

Comment: Yes. I disinherited permissions for the sub-site and I removed all users other than those specified from the permissions page.

Comment: On permission page ,If there  is message say "Some content on this site has different permissions from what you see here.  Show these items." then click on "Show these items" link and check that any contents within  has unique permissions.

Comment: Yes, I did that when I disinherited permissions. It does not show anything as having unique permissions, which is why I am struggling.

Comment: do you use the same groups as for the parent site or did you create new groups for the sub-site?

Comment: I created new groups for the sub-site (and any other sub-sites that do not inherit permissions)

Answer (score 1):

The 'View Items' permission lets the other users to access the subsite, try un-checking this permission. As default, users are given permission level 'Limited Access'. **Somehow**, these listed permissions may refer to 'Read' permission level:

- Allow: View Web Analytics Data
- Allow: Browse Directories
- Allow: View Items
- Allow: View Pages
- Allow: Enumerate Permissions
- Allow: Open Items
- Allow: View Versions
- Allow: Browse User Information
- Allow: View Application Pages
- Allow: Use Remote Interfaces
- Allow: Use Client Integration Features
- Allow: Open

PS: Most of the listed permissions only (refers to the Read permission level) but not all.

Refer to this [site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx) for the list of permissions and permission levels.